How do I make a terminal command for my compiler?
I tried searching for an answer but I can't seem to find the right 'term' for it, I would go back and forth and type 'how to create your own environment variable' or 'how to create your own path variable' and things like that but I think I'm really not using the right word for it.
Basically, what I want to do is basically how any other compiler, runtime environment, or programming language have these commands on the terminal, like if you want gcc to compile for you, you just set the environment variable and type in:
gcc <gcc-command-here>
I want to do the same but like this:
compilername <place-file-to-compile-here>
but where do I actually start in order to make something like this?

You write, compile, and link compilername.exe (Windows) or an executable file called compilername on Unix/Linux. This trivial question hardly deserves the [tag:compiler-construction] tag.

I don't understand why you tagged this with terminal, since the problem is related to the shell you run inside your terminal app and not to the terminal app itself. As for what you want to do, I think it is now the time for you to learn about the PATH variable. BTW, googling for this problem could be done with the search string how to execute a program by just typing its name.

If you on linux all you need to do is set the path of the program you want in your shell. For example in bash I would edit the file .bashrc in your home directory to include a line like this:
export PATH=$PATH:/home/YOURNAME/compilername

then where ever you run compilername it will run.
